# Pip and Python not recognized in project with virtualenv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, jetbrains-ide, virtual-environment

I'm new to python, and I downloaded a repository I'll start working on, but I am facing an issue. In the terminal in PyCharm, it says that both "pip" and "python" are not recognized internal or external commands, and when opening the project, it says it cannot load django facet.

I'm using Python 3.6, which is the same the project uses, and all commands seem to work on my cmd, just not inside the PyCharm terminal. Another thing I noticed is the terminal begins with (my_venv_name), so it's someting like:

`(my_venv_name) C:\Users\my_user\PycharmProjects\ProjectName>`

Which I asume means my virtualenv is properly activated and linked to the project. By the messages I receive, I guess there's either something wrong with my virtualenv or with my Pycharm configuration, but I've been looking and googling and can't seem to find where the problem might be, any help would be really appreciated.

The error displayed for django is this:

[image]

And in my project interpreter settings, I see django should be installed, but then again, I think I could be misunderstanding how this works.

[image]

Comment: Did you specifically use "Import project " in Pycharm?

Comment: The facet issue is related to JetBrains editor, not to virtual environment (https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_model/facet.html)

Comment: I opened Pycharm and selected the "Open from git" option, and I just copied the repository URL

Comment: Do you use PyCharm Professional? Django support is available only there.

Comment: You were right, @user2235698, this error disappear when I upgraded to the Professional version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error went away when I upgraded to Pycharm Professional, which has been pointed out to me  by user2235698, that is intended behaviour, so the problem was fixed.